# Developing a kernel patch or driver for windows?

Tags: windows, driver, kernel

How long, approximately, would it take to develop a kernel patch or driver for the windows NT kernel/series of kernels, that would introduce new functionality, or replace existing functionality?

For example, to add in a different encryption algorithm, or to implement some sort of new security model.

What are the advantages/disadvantages between actually writing a kernel patch, and a driver?

Can a driver be theoretically bypassed, in a way a kernel patch cannot?

I understand the windows kernel is proprietary and it is hard to write a kernel patch for it, but this is exactly what several companies, notably AV companies do, without cooperation from Microsoft, so it is possible...

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A kernel patch is not the way to go in windows. Under windows you install hooks in the kernel, or load drivers against a static (documented) API, which will not change in the near future.

Answer (score 7):

> A different encryption algorithm

This is done by extending the encryption provider. There is a framework where you can do that.

> new security model

What new security model?

- If you want more specific control over one application, you build a sandbox.
- If you want more specific control over an OS, you put the OS into a virtual machine.
- If you have something completely new, you have to write a new kernel. Right management is really a broad topic, where you have to touch every entry point to get your solution to work.

> Can a driver be theoretically bypassed, in a way a kernel patch cannot?

No and yes ... How do you think a driver changes a security model?

> but this is exactly what several companies, notably AV companies do.

No, they don't. They have a kernel driver, which hooks into the right functions. Most AV software hooks the ReadFile/WriteFile/CreateFile APIs, in which they check for 'malicious code-sequences'. This is not a security model. Its just a binary 'May access/may not access' check.

Comment: +1 for Most AV software hooks the ReadFile/WriteFile/CreateFile APIs.

Comment: Your answer is full of a lot of incorrect info, and does not address the question asked. Read up on KPP, and why it was such an issue.

Comment: Cleaned the 'wrong' bits. But i don't see, that the information is so wrong when you see the question. To repeat the thing to take away 'You cannot easily add a new security model'.

Comment: If he wants to add a new security model, i.e. not ACL based, something like GRSecurity, then surely the only way to do that is with kernel patching, and not with drivers? If KPP is a problem, he would probably have to get permission from microsoft somnehow.....

Answer (score 1):

the proper way to modify how the kernel works is to write a filter driver that modifies or snoops at information transferred between drivers.

that is the closest thing to a legitimate patch

with regard to patching the kernel function tables...you should not do that because: it will not work in x64 edtions. since it will not work in x64 edtion, you cannot WLK certify your driver even for 32-bits. and if you cannot certify your driver, you will end up having an undecertified driver which is highly discourgaed (for example, you cannot preinstall on a computer and then wlk certify the machine).